# How do you assign the content of "{}" to a shell variable in "find --exec"

Tags: bash, find

I was trying to write a script that looped through each xml file in a directory and run make NAME= where NM was the filename minus the `.xml`, the place where I got stuck was assigning the `{}` placeholder to a variable. As

```
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec foo=$(echo {}); gmake NAME=$FOO \;
```

does not work as nothing is assigned to `$FOO`.

Comment: I could have sworn I have done something like this before and it worked: `find . -exec TMP=1; echo $TMP \;`  But this morning this gives the error "find: missing argument to \`-exec'
;" and I'm baffled what the heck I did that worked and why this is giving such an unexpected error!  I *know* I have done this lots of times even with a pipe and now everything I try is an error.  Even `find . -exec TMP=1 \;` gives errors!

Answer (score 15):

After much searching on IRC someone pointed me to the following answer

```
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'echo "$1"' bash {} \;
```

or for my example (with the string cut removed to save confusion)

```
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'gmake NAME="$1"' bash {} \;
```

The way this works is bash takes the parameters after `-c` as arguments, `bash {}` is needed so that the contents of `{}` is assigned to `$1` not `$0`, and `bash` is used to fill in `$0`. It's not only a placeholder as the contents of that `$0` is used in error messages for instance so you don't want to use things like `_` or `''`

To process more that one file per invocation of `bash`, you can do:

```
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec bash -c '
   ret=0
   for file do
       gmake NAME="$file" || ret=$?
   done
   exit "$ret"' bash {} +
```

That one has the added benefit that if any of the `gmake` invocations fails, it will reported in `find`'s exit status.

More info can be taken from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions

Comment: `_` for example won't work in sh? Which `sh`?

Comment: I have run across this problem before. `find`'s handling of argument substitution is pretty weak. Passing to a shell script (inline or otherwise) seems to be the only way to really get a handle on the arguments.

Comment: `_` is a bash predefined variable (not defined in dash for instance): "At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname  used  to  invoke  
the  shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list."

Comment: @muru the strict implementation of /bin/sh from what i was reading as opposed to most distro's that now don't ship it and just symlink something else like bash or dash

Comment: @muru In the Bourne shell, the `_` is passed as `$1`. But apart from `/bin/sh` on Solaris (as opposed to `/bin/ksh` or `sh` which should be `/usr/bin/xpg4/sh` or `/usr/bin/xpg6/sh`) and for some 20-year-old servers running Unix variants that haven't received a security update in a decade, there are no Bourne shells anymore. `sh` today means a POSIX shell, and these all pass `_` as `$0`.

Comment: The edit has made it clear. The original text made it seem like the underscore itself was a problem.

Comment: This helped me figure out that I can even pass along other variables, like so: `find . -iname "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'echo "$1/$2"' _ {} $OTHER \;`, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Simotek's answer is awesome!  Changed the format so that I can rename a HUGE amount of files in a one-liner...

```
find * -name "*.sh" -exec bash -c 'OLD=$1; NEW=$(echo $OLD | sed s/OLD-NAME.sh/NEW_NAME.sh/g); mv "$OLD" "$NEW"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Your code would fail on filenames contain filename globbing characters and names tha start with a dash.  It also seems to assume that all found names are `OLD-NAME.sh`.  I don't quite know why you use `/g` at the end of the `sed` expression, or why you're using `sed` at all here as you would get the effect by just doing `NEW=NEW_NAME.sh`, assuming the old name was `OLD-NAME.sh` that is. You may want to fix your code so that it's actually testable and does what it says it does.